# Como identificar percentual de uso de memória para executar comando de limpeza de cache?

Tags: linux, memória, bash

Sabemos que o comando para limpeza de cache de memória é este:

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Porém, como fazer um executável com uma condição (if() else()), para que este comando seja executado apenas quando o uso da memória atingir 80% ou mais através do crontab?

Algo parecido com isto:

```
#!/bin/sh
if (uso da memoria > 80%){
    sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
}
```

Comment: Olá Anderson. Em qual parte você está com dificuldade? Fazer o if em batch script? Extrair o percentual de memória usada? Configurar o job no cron? Se você preparar um mvce demonstrando o problema fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: minha dificuldade está em fazer um if de acordo com o percentual de memória utilizado. não sei por onde começar.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi meu problema com o código abaixo:

```
#!/bin/bash

# total de memória instalada  32991100 (32 GB)

# total em 90% de uso 29691990

MAXIMO="29691990"

MONITOR=$(free | grep Mem)
USADA=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $3 }')
LIVRE=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $4 }')

if [ "$USADA" -gt "$MAXIMO" ]
then
    sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
fi
```

A tarefa cron executará a cada 5 minutos e se identificar que o uso de memória está acima de 90%, limpará o cache de memória.

Comment: Talvez você saiba isso, mas não deixa de ser legal ter a informação aqui. Limpar o cache da VM no Linux apenas para liberar memória quase sempre é uma má ideia. O Linux tenta usar sempre o máximo de memória possível para otimizar o desempenho, e quando ele precisa realmente de memória para aplicação, ele tenta limpar as páginas de cache menos "importantes". Quando você força a limpeza de todo o cache, pro Linux não vai fazer tanta diferença em termos de memória livre, mas você perde todo o desempenho que ganharia com arquivos muito acessados direto da memória.

Comment: Realmente concordo contigo Eitch, isto não é uma boa prática, mas, depende da situação. Tenho um servidor web e sou obrigado a fazer isto, uma vez que não posso reiniciar a máquina quando o cache da memória está cheio. Então esta solução me caiu como uma luva. Além do mais na minha situação a limpeza ocorre a cada 2 dias. Então em caso de desempenho não será muito afetado.

Comment: Mas aí é que tá, por que você é obrigado a fazer isso para limpar o cache? Afinal, se o Linux precisa de memória, ele desaloca o cache do mesmo jeito para conseguir mais memória pra aplicação :)

Comment: Passei a fazer isto depois que percebi uma lentidão no servidor e que nenhum aplicativo respondia devido a memória estar com 100% de uso. Talvez então haja outra configuração a fazer, pois seu eu não utilizar desta prática em poucas horas meu servidor "congela".